# How do you suppress the ggdark warning message when using a function in lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2, warnings, lapply

I'm plotting my way through a list of data using pblapply. The plots use `ggdark`, which prints an error message each time it plots. It's messing up my progress bar for pblapply. I've read around and tried `suppressWarnings()`, but it doesn't work. Any ideas for how to suppress this warning message?

```
Inverted geom defaults of fill and color/colour.
To change them back, use invert_geom_defaults().
```

Here's a demo:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(pbapply)
library(ggdark)

# Make a list
p = split(diamonds, f=diamonds$cut)

# Open pdf
pdf("diamonds.pdf", onefile = T)

# Iterate through the list
pblapply(p, function(x) {
  
  print(
    ggplot(x) + 
      geom_point(aes(carat, price, color = cut)) + 
      scale_y_continuous(label = scales::dollar) +
      guides(color = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
      labs(title = "Prices of 50,000 round cut diamonds by carat and cut",
           x = "Weight (carats)",
           y = "Price in US dollars",
           color = "Quality of the cut") +
      dark_theme_bw()
  )
  
  # Revert to geom default
  invert_geom_defaults()
  
})

# Close pdf
dev.off()
```

Comment: Please add any non-base R package loads to your script to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a warning, it's a message. You need `suppressMessages` rather than `suppressWarnings`

```r
pblapply(p, function(x) {
  
  print(
    suppressMessages(
    ggplot(x) + 
      geom_point(aes(carat, price, color = cut)) + 
      scale_y_continuous(label = scales::dollar) +
      guides(color = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
      labs(title = "Prices of 50,000 round cut diamonds by carat and cut",
           x = "Weight (carats)",
           y = "Price in US dollars",
           color = "Quality of the cut") +
      dark_theme_bw()
  )
  )
  
  # Revert to geom default
  invert_geom_defaults()
  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you assign the plot to `p`, using `theme_bw()`, and then add `dark_mode(verbose=F)` to `p`?

```
pblapply(p, function(x) {
  
  p = ggplot(x) + 
        geom_point(aes(carat, price, color = cut)) + 
        scale_y_continuous(label = scales::dollar) +
        guides(color = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
        labs(title = "Prices of 50,000 round cut diamonds by carat and cut",
             x = "Weight (carats)",
             y = "Price in US dollars",
            color = "Quality of the cut") + 
    theme_bw()
  
  print(p + dark_mode(verbose=F))
})
```